# Vuetify 2 toolbar ans 1 navigation drawer with 1 toolbar above the navigation drawer

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to achieve something like this : 
[image]

Actually i have this :
[image]

My problem is that currently I can not put the first toolbar above the navigation drawer.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar app class="elevation-1">
        <span>Toolbar1</span>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-toolbar app class="mt-5 elevation-1" style="top: 16px">
      <span>Toolbar2</span>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-navigation-drawer app fixed permanent>
      <v-toolbar></v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile-title class="title">Filter</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-toolbar>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-content class="mt-5">
      <HomePage/>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would first add `clipped-left` to the first toolbar and move it under the `navigation-drawer` like so.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer app fixed permanent>
      <v-toolbar></v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile-title class="title">Filter</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-toolbar>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-toolbar app clipped-left class="elevation-1">
      <span>Toolbar1</span>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-toolbar app class="mt-5 elevation-1" style="top: 16px">
      <span>Toolbar2</span>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content class="mt-5">
      <HomePage/>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Though, I strongly advice you to **get familiar with the available props** on the Vuetify documentation (regarding those 2 components) to be able to get exactly what you want

- [Navigation Drawer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers)
- [Toolbar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars)

---

**Update**

I did some ugly fixes to the previous answer to handle the responsiveness and clean the code a bit.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer clipped permanent app>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-title class="title">Menu Item #1</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-toolbar clipped-left app>
      <span>Toolbar</span>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-toolbar class="mt-5" :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? 'top: 8px' : 'top: 16px'" app>
      <span>SubToolbar</span>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? 'padding-top: 112px' : 'padding-top: 128px'">
      <v-container fluid>
        Content
        <!-- <router-view></router-view> -->
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted ! I had already tried the clipped but did not specify left .... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just answerd another similar question, despite I did it wrong first time, I think I redeemed myself on the edit, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523432/vuetify-app-navigation-drawer-does-not-push-content-to-the-side)

Anyhow, I was wanting to do the same, so I changed the v-content to v-main, for the actual content.
Also, used the app, permanent and clipped, without the fixed prop.
The app navbar also should have clipped-right in your case.
That did the trick for me

```
<v-app-bar
app
clipped-left
color="#c4161c"
dark
>
...
</v-app-bar>

...

<v-navigation-drawer
app
permanent        
clipped
class="mt-100"        
>
...
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [vuetify wireframes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/wireframes/) for an example.
The feature is a bit hidden, but if you click on on of the examples, like "[Discord](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/wireframes/discord/)", you will see a blue github icon in the bottom right corner. Just click it and it will guide you to the [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/wireframes/discord.vue).