# Vuetify - App Navigation Drawer does not push content to the side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Navigation Drawer which does not push content to the side on moving it from `mini.variant` to `opened`.

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  class="chatbar--gradient"
  app
  right
  :mini-variant.sync="closed"
  mini-variant-width="70"
  width="250px"
></v-navigation-drawer>
```

`App.vue`:

```html
<v-app dark>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <navigation-bar></navigation-bar>
  <v-slide-y-transition>
    <chat-sidebar></chat-sidebar>**
    <!-- THIS IS THE MODAL FROM ABOVE -->
    **
  </v-slide-y-transition>
  <v-content>
    <keep-alive>
      <transition name="fade">
        <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
      </transition>
    </keep-alive>
    <display-name-entry-modal></display-name-entry-modal>
  </v-content>
  <v-footer v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp" tile padless height="3px" app class="pageFooter"></v-footer>
  <bottom-nav v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"></bottom-nav>
</v-app>
```

Comment: What version of Vuetify?

Comment: @CathyHa 2.0.4 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuetify: Why is the sidebar laying over the other element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855927/vuetify-why-is-the-sidebar-laying-over-the-other-element)