# Vuetify: Why is the sidebar laying over the other element?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My sidebar is laying over the router-view but it should be "blocking" the space.
[image: screenshot of sidebar]

In my App.vue there is following code

```
<template>
    <v-app id="app">
        <v-container>
            <sidebar class="d-block"/>

            <router-view class="d-block"></router-view>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Due to the d-block class of Vuetify I'd expect the sidebar to not overlay.

The sidebar is basically copied from the original API

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        :color="color"
        :permanent="permanent"
        :app="app"
        dark
        >
            <v-list dense nav class="py-0">
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>Application</v-list-item-title>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle>Subtext</v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item-content>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link>
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>

                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `d-block` class, and a search of the Vuetify docs didn't show me anything. I would get rid of it; you don't need a `d-block` class to make the navigation drawer push the content aside when it opens.

That being said, I don't think you want to wrap everything in `<v-container>` like you're doing. Try structuring your app code like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <sidebar />
    <v-content>
      <router-view />
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

And don't wrap your `<v-navigation-drawer>` in `<v-container>`, either. You want it like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    permanent
    app
    dark
    color="primary"
  >
    // Contents
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Then, have the views displayed by your `<router-view>` use `<v-container>`:

```html
<template>
  <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
    // View content
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested it but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Comment: @NullOrNotNull Maybe I don't understand what you're going for. Do you want the navigation drawer to be on top of the page content when it opens, or do you want the drawer to push the page content aside when it opens?

Comment: I want the sidebar to be persistent. It should push the content from the router view and not overlay it

Comment: @NullOrNotNull Make sure you get rid of all instances of `class="d-block"`. I don't think you don't want that anywhere. You definitely don't need to apply that class in order to get the nav drawer to push the content aside. I expanded my answer with more detail.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I changed my coding accordingly to your suggestion and its working fine now!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a definitive answer, whether the `<v-navigation-drawer>` component pushes content or overlays it depends on the `app` property being present. With `<v-navigation-drawer app>` it becomes part of the app's layout and will resize your content. Without it, it will overlay on top of your content.

See the API documentation here for a good explanation of the `app` property:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#api-props