# How to put navigation-drawer under app-bar for mobile in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, navigation-drawer

Desktop Mode Image

[image: Desktop Mode Image]

Mobile Mode Image

[image: Mobile Mode Image]

The "clipped" option works fine in desktop mode.

However, in mobile mode, menu items are hidden by the app-bar. ("Dashboard" item is hidden.)

How can I put the navigation-drawer under the app-bar even in mobile mode?

My Source:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark clipped-left>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer app v-model="drawer" absolute clipped>
      <v-list nav>
        <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link>
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-main> </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {},

  data: () => ({
    drawer: null,
    items: [
          { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard' },
          { title: 'Photos', icon: 'mdi-image' },
          { title: 'About', icon: 'mdi-help-box' },
        ]
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: And if you add CSS property `style="display:block;` to `v-app-bar` and `v-navigation-drawer`, does it change something ?

Comment: @zerbene thanks, but it's not working, same result.

Comment: Can this help you ? https://gist.github.com/oliverbth05/9834e9114b52b1f4ea77a0ae2d353e2f , like adding `<v-spacer></v-spacer>` between `v-app-bar` and `v-navigation-drawer`

Comment: @zerbene thanks, 
As you said, I added <v-spacer></v-spacer> between v-app-bar and v-navigation-drawer and tested it. but it's not working, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me.

[image: Vuetify navigation drawer under app-bar]

```html
<v-app id="inspire">
   <v-overlay
      :value="drawer"
      z-index="4"
    >
    </v-overlay>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      app
      clipped
      hide-overlay
      :style="{ top: $vuetify.application.top + 'px', zIndex: 4 }"
    >
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar
      app
      clipped-left
      dark
      color="#447fa6"
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
</v-app>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jorje/pen/JjbqvqJ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 4):

Below code worked for me.

```
<v-app-bar app clipped-left>
  <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-if="!permanent" @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
  <v-toolbar-title v-text="title" />
</v-app-bar>
<v-navigation-drawer
  v-model="drawer"
  :permanent="permanent"
  expand-on-hover
  clipped
  app
>
...
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I am able to do what I want using this link [Vuetify 2 toolbar ans 1 navigation drawer with 1 toolbar above the navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867477/vuetify-2-toolbar-ans-1-navigation-drawer-with-1-toolbar-above-the-navigation-dr)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `:mobile-breakpoint="0"` to navigation drawer fixes the issue.
No mobile styling is added to the navigation drawer and it works same as on desktop.
EX:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
  app
  v-model="drawerOpen"
  :clipped="true"
  :mobile-breakpoint="0"
 >...
```

Comment: Something in the mobile styles, in conjunction with clipped, is causing an issue.  But setting the mobile-breakpoint to 0 changes the behavior of the menu. In mobile, it pops over the content. Without mobile, it pushes the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `app` from `<v-app-bar app>`.
I don't know why, but for me it is working.

Answer (score 0):

these changes made it work for me:

`<v-app-bar :clipped-left="true" :clipped-right="true"></v-app-bar>`

depending on what you need and which side you want to add the navigation drawer

then in navigation drawer add the clipped attribute as well

`<v-navigation-drawer :clipped="true"></v-navigation-drawer>`